# Create and run library with junit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I would like to create a library with junit integration tests than can be run from multiple projects. How can I approach it?

Is it possible to create a library jar with junit tests?

How can I run all tests from a dependency jar?

Comment: Which code are the tests supposed to test?

Comment: @EricSchaefer tests are supposed to test projects in which they are included as library. We have rest projects that expose rest api. We have several projects with the same rest api, I would like to write common tests for different projects and include them in these projects and run them on cicd.